# How to replace matching rows by one column (ID's column match) between 2 sheets - App Script

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 sheets with identical headers (36 columns)

Sheet 1 named "Source"
Sheet 2 named "Target"

Both of them have in last column AJ an unique ID

How do I replace the rows from Target with the ones from Source if ID's (column AJ) are equal?

Thx
-I reformulated the question to be more specific

Here a sheet with less columns https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rTvInVG8hR06V2tPEmjqoDvSs_9-QrW08-oW6m-yHnk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I need help with this one, please.

Answer (score 0):

```
function copywithMatchingIds() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh = ss.getSheetByName("Source");
  const svs = ssh.getRange(2,1,ssh.getLastRow() - 1, ssh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const tsh = ss.getSheetByName("Target");
  const tvs = tsh.getRange(2,tsh.getLastColumn(),tsh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat();
  svs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let idx = tvs.indexOf(r[6]);
    if(~idx) {
      tsh.getRange(idx + 2,1,1,r.length).setValues([r]);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi!
Thx for answering. In line 5 I was getting error and modified to 'ssh.getLastColumn'

Result of this function was almost what I need.
But instead to replace the existing row in target sheet it copied the matching IDs to rows: 37, 73 and 109.
In Source sheet I have only 7 rows including header and in target only 4 rows including header. And identical ID's where 3.

Comment: Source sheet; https://ibb.co/6H2Q24D
Target sheet; https://ibb.co/znhwt6z

Comment: I don't know other method. There are many columns.
Like I said it copied the rows from source to target but not by overwriting them. Instead was copied to other lines down in the sheet.

Comment: I think copied the matching rows in every 36 rows down in the target sheet. :)

1+36 = 37; 37+36= 73; 73+36=109

Comment: Sorry if I didn't specified that if ID's are match to copy rows from target and overwrite the corresponding rows by ID's in target sheet.

Comment: Perhaps a public link to the spreadsheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rTvInVG8hR06V2tPEmjqoDvSs_9-QrW08-oW6m-yHnk/edit?usp=sharing